Does executing a Lua script in Redis block the entire Redis server or just the database being accessed?
Details:
Atomic Operations: I understand that Lua scripts in Redis are executed atomically. However, I need clarification on whether the atomicity affects only the Redis database being accessed by the script or the entire Redis server.
Concurrency: Will executing a Lua script block other clients from accessing Redis, especially if they are working with the same keys involved in the Lua script's operations?
Performance: Are Lua scripts generally efficient for operations like checking queues and managing locks in Redis, or should I consider alternative approaches for high-throughput scenarios?
Objective:
I want to ensure that my application can handle multiple concurrent requests efficiently without unnecessary blocking or performance degradation due to Lua script execution.
Request:
Could someone clarify the impact of Lua script execution in Redis on overall server performance and concurrency? Additionally, any best practices or alternatives for managing distributed locks and queues in Redis would be greatly appreciated.
Request:
Could someone clarify the impact of Lua script execution in Redis on overall server performance and concurrency? Additionally, any best practices or alternatives for managing distributed locks and queues in Redis would be greatly appreciated.

How is this related to Python or FastAPI?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
